# Javascript/React code - control/page won't render in fileReader.onload

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react page and one of my inputs is a file upload.  When loading, I want to read in the file (it's JSON) and then show the file as a tree to allow my users to select nodes (rules) to run against another dataset.  BUT, when I pick the JSON file and the 'onload' event handler actually fires off, the page just stops rendering, I get a blank screen.  I'm not sure why, I can't see any errors, but I AM IGNORANT with react and kinda new with javascript as well.  So, this is quite likely just a dumb thing I'm doing.  Can someone point me at what I'm doing wrong here?

```
    handleRules(event) {
        const ruleRdr = new FileReader();
        ruleRdr.onload = async (e) => {
            const rBuf = (e.target.result);
            const rData = JSON.parse(new TextDecoder().decode(rBuf));
            // the data is there, but it's not mapping into the tree...!?!?!?
            const tree = {
                name: "QA/QC Rules",
                id: 1,
                toggled: true,
                children: rData.map((wFlow, index) => ({
                    name: wFlow.WorkflowName,
                    id: index,
                    children: wFlow.Rules.map((rule, idx) => ({
                        name: rule.RuleName,
                        id: idx
                    }))
                }))
            };
            this.setState({ ruleData: rData, hasRules: true, treeData: tree });
        }
        ruleRdr.readAsArrayBuffer(event.target.files[0]);
    }
```

EDIT #1:  I don't think it's the code above now, I think it might be my tree library ([react-treebeard](https://github.com/storybookjs/react-treebeard)) or my ignorance on how I'm using it.  The code produces what I think is useable data, but it isn't rendering it out.

```
{
  "name": "QA/QC Rules",
  "id": 1,
  "toggled": true,
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "COMP",
      "id": 0,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "ParentMustHaveCat",
          "id": 0
        },
        {
          "name": "ParentMustHaveMfg",
          "id": 1
        },
        {
          "name": "ParentMustHaveFamily",
          "id": 2
        },
        {
          "name": "SymbolsMustHaveFamily",
          "id": 3
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "PNLCOMP",
      "id": 1,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "ParentMustHaveCat",
          "id": 0
        },
        {
          "name": "ParentMustHaveMfg",
          "id": 1
        },
        {
          "name": "ParentMustHaveFamily",
          "id": 2
        },
        {
          "name": "SymbolsMustHaveFamily",
          "id": 3
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "PNLTERM",
      "id": 2,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "ParentMustHaveCat",
          "id": 0
        },
        {
          "name": "ParentMustHaveMfg",
          "id": 1
        },
        {
          "name": "ParentMustHaveFamily",
          "id": 2
        },
        {
          "name": "SymbolsMustHaveFamily",
          "id": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I switched to MUI since it has more components that I will want to use anyway.  I got a similar issue with it as well and realized that I have duplicate IDs between the parent and the children, and was creating a kind of lock when trying to compare parent and child IDs in the MUI library.  Totally on me - I'm dumb.